# Azure search index with always encrypted table in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Is it possible to create from a azure search index(portal or .net sdk) on azure sql table having few columns as always encrypted.

When I try the same encrypted columns are not visible in the fields mapping on the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported using an indexer, but we've added this to the backlog.